# Sharing a debug key on an Android project that uses the Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, keystore, api-key

I am working on an Android project with a few others that utilizes the Google Maps API. The problem is, currently, I am hard-coding my debug API key as an attribute on the MapView element. Since my debug key only works on my machine because only my machine has the keystore tied to that key, what's the best way that I can work with my project partners on getting Google Maps set up properly? It would be horrible if we had to manually change the hard-coded debug key each time we wanted to get it to work on our own machines.

Also, if this is necessary information, not all of us are using Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since my debug key only works on my machine because only my machine has the keystore tied to that key, what's the best way that I can work with my project partners on getting Google Maps set up properly?

Copy your `debug.keystore` file between those partners.

Comment: I was thinking about that. Is this the suggested method? In addition, we are planning to open source this once we are "done". At this point, what would be the best course of action, considering that we might do a release to the Market/Play?

Comment: @kibibyte: "Is this the suggested method?" -- either share the keystores or have everyone supply their own API key. "At this point, what would be the best course of action" -- you will need a production keystore and a corresponding API key. Do not include keystores in your OSS release, particularly the production key (as then you are only one hacked Google account away from having your app replaced with malware on Play).